# performSelectorOnMainThread method not call

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsthread, performselector

I have created a method that is running in new thread.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(setmostpopularReq:) toTarget:self withObject:mostPopulerstring];
```

After completed this method i send all data to main thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getmostpopularResponse:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But some time my main thread method not calling.

i used

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{[self getmostpopularResponse:mostPopularList];});
```

But this is also have the same problem some time its calling method or some time not calling.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Well I don't think GCD is broken, so how are you validating that the method is being called?

Comment: I trace with breakpoint.its not calling these "getmostpopularResponse" my event is not coming on front after completed all function its must be goes to from but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create a delegate with which you could notify the main thread after the
completion of the detached thread

Also another solution would be to create an NSOperation and NSOperationQueue instead of a new thread. There you can schedule what you want. For me looks easier, though it depends on you.

Here is a link to help you more with NSOperation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/ManagingConcurrency/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for respond me would you please give me a simple example. My requirement is I have to send a webservice call in background so that i can do some event on font and after getting response I will display response data on front.

Answer (score 0):

I will write this really quickly.

```
@protocol RespondDelegate
- (void)notifyWithRespond:(NSData *)data;
@end

@interface ContactWebServiceOperation:NSOperation
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@end

@implementation ContactWebServiceOperation
@synthesize delegate;

// initialize here.
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
{
   if ([self = [super init]) { 
      self.delegate = delegate;
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)main 
{
    if (self.isCancelled) return;
    if (nil != delegate) {
        // Do your work here...
        work();

        // When finished notify the delegate with the new data.
        [delegate notifyWithRespond:your_data_here];

        // Or
        [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processImageForDownloadOperation:)
            withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
@end



// Now on the view that you want to present the received results 
// you have to do one thing.
// Let's say that your view is called View1


@interface View1 : UIViewController<RespondDelegate>
// Here put whatever you like.
@end

@implementation View1

// Put here all your code.


- (void)notifyWithRespond:(NSData *)data
{
    // Here you will handle your new data and you will update your view.
}

@end
```

If I understand correct this should work.
Also, you can change the NSData to whatever you like, as long as you perform the appropriate conversions later.

If it doesn't work take a look on the link from Apple, maybe I have some typo or something.
But in general it looks solid.